# Jquery help onclick option

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to render finder when the form gets submitted.

```
$('option').click(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
$("#konkurrancer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("finder")) %>");
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please provide more information.

Comment: How to submit the form when a option is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your code to:

```
$('select').change(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
$("#konkurrancer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("finder")) %>");
```